# How to add a success message after submitting Word form?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word form that is locked and only has fields that users can fill in. When they get to the end, there is a submit button which is an active x control with the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim bStarted As Boolean
Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next

If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "Document needs to be saved first"
     Exit Sub
End If

Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
     Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     bStarted = True
End If

Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oItem
     .To = "email address"
     .Subject = "New subject"
     'Add the document as an attachment, you can use the .displayname property
     'to set the description that's used in the message
    .Attachments.Add Source:=ActiveDocument.FullName, Type:=olByValue, _
       DisplayName:="Document as attachment"
     .Send
End With

If bStarted Then
     oOutlookApp.Quit
End If

Set oItem = Nothing
Set oOutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I added the Outlook library to the references so when I click on the button it does send the email as expected with the Word document as an attachment. The problem is that there is no message telling the user that it has worked. I worry that users will just hit the button over and over again sending multiple emails. I don't usually do VBA, but it is necessary for my current task, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `MsgBox "Your message was sent"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me adding a MsgBox line at the end of the procedure should do the job. For example:

```
MsgBox "Document sent as e-mail"
```

You can format the message, such as change title, the buttons and the icon, if you wish. Look up the method in the VBA Language Help for more information.

I also see a possible problem with your code. Near the beginning you have:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

That essentially turns off all errors - if anything goes wrong there will be no notification. This is generally a very BAD idea. If used, it should only be for a couple of lines, then you either resume normal error notifications or turn on error handling. I assume it's originally in your code for the part about starting up the Outlook application. That's fine, it's more or less standard... But after the End If you should add a line such as:

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a  msgbox("Message Sent") after .send or after ooutlookapp.quit